# Where are the tokens from Open Id Connect being stored?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Open ID Connect and requesting tokens from Azure Active Directory. I am using the authorization code flow, so I am receiving both the id_token and the access_token. I am using .NET Core.

My configuration of Open Id Connect is as follows:

```
options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
options.SaveTokens = true;
```

Notice the Save Tokens set to **true**

When the user is logged in, I am able to retrieve both the tokens as follows:

```cs
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

My question is, where these tokens are actually being saved, and how can I configure how these tokens are being saved?

I also heard that in the authorization code flow, the identity provider will return the authorization code, and the server would then use that code to request the tokens. However, I am not doing any of that programmatically and I am still able to retrieve the tokens. Is this something handled automatically with Open Id Connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Where these tokens are actually being saved?**

As the `OpenID Connect protocol` diagram architecture describe, When a new session is started, a new cookie is returned to control this session. This "sesion cookie" is created based on "ID Token" and as long as this cookie is valid, user will be considered as authenticated. As you are using, OpenID Connect (OIDC), it create the cookie and save token there. you could refer this [docs](https://jamuro-blog.azurewebsites.net/post/managing-azure-ad-sessions-and-ajax-calls-in-aspnet-mvc-apps-with-open-id-connect-authentication)

**How can I configure how these tokens?**

If you want to configure your token mechanism Microsoft provides library fro that. You can use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) or [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) for your own configuration.

**Is this something handled automatically with Open Id Connect?**

Thought its has some background mechanism but you have to use authentication library to handle on your application code. You could refer [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)

For more details you could refer flowing docs

1. [Authentication implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-add-connected-service)
2. [Authentication Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)
3. [Code sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)

Answer (score 0):

`response_type` is set to `code` indicating that you are using the Authorization Code Flow.

When you use OIDC auth code flow along with clientid and clientsecret to [get token](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/29/oidc-user-auth-aspnet-core), the work process is as below:

[image]

1.The user clicks Login within the regular web application.

2.Auth0's SDK redirects the user to the Auth0 Authorization Server (/authorize endpoint).

3.Your Auth0 Authorization Server redirects the user to the login and authorization prompt.

4.The user authenticates using one of the configured login options and may see a consent page listing the permissions Auth0 will give to the regular web application.

5.Your Auth0 Authorization Server redirects the user back to the application with an authorization code.

6.Auth0's SDK sends this code to the Auth0 Authorization Server (/oauth/token endpoint) along with the application's Client ID and Client Secret.

7.Your Auth0 Authorization Server verifies the code, Client ID, and Client Secret.

8.Your Auth0 Authorization Server responds with an ID Token and Access Token (and optionally, a Refresh Token).